# Keep volume when you disconnect speakers

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have Windows 7 and I'm using the Nvidia on-board sound chip. It sets the volume to something much too loud, when I disconnect the speakers. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like something probably controlled by the sound driver itself.  Is there any kind of options/settings/dialog that you can access for that chip? (check control panel).  That's where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 remembers and resets volumes based on the listening device plugged in (say speakers vs. headphones).

Have you tried adjusting the volume with the speakers unplugged?  Hopefully it will remember the chosen levels for both unplugged and plugged-in states.